# Trigger water animation on button click in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to apply water filling effect when clicked on the button using `4` steps like `25%`, `50%`, `75%` and `100%`. Is it possible with below CSS animation?

Could anyone please help?

```css
#banner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#banner .fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="fill">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<div><br/><button>Add water</button></div>
```

Comment: You can assign the animation to a class rather than the id and add/toggle the class on button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need javascript to add interaction on button, like this

```js
var fillPortion = 0 // the first state is 0%
document.getElementById('add-water-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let height = document.getElementById('banner').clientHeight // get container height
  // prevent added more than 100%
  if (fillPortion < 100) {
    fillPortion += 25 // added 25% on every click
    // since the translate Y is backward (full is 0px, empty is 150px), then the fill portion must be backward to (the first click is 75%, second click is 50%, last click is 0%)
    document.querySelector('#banner .fill').style.transform = 'translate(0, ' + ((100 - fillPortion) / 100) * height + 'px)'
  } else {
    // add code if already full
  }
})
```

```css
#banner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
/* add first state */
#banner .fill{
   transform: translate(0, 150px);
   transition: all cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4) 4s;
}
/* run animation when class .animate added */
/* EDIT: you dont need animation because it can be done only with transform translate */
/* #banner .fill.animate{
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 */
#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="fill">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- add id on button to make DOM interaction easier -->
<div><br/><button id="add-water-btn">Add water</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change your this " #banner .fill " to ".fill-animation" and toggle them on btn click**

```
//
.fill-animation{
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
 

//JS

const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const fill = document.querySelector('.fill');

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  
      fill.classList.remove('fill-animation')
      setTimeout(()=>{
           fill.classList.add('fill-animation')
      },10) 
  
})
```